# Irvine ch10. Three-Operand Instructions using Macro in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to make 4 macros and trying to calculate 4 operations with it. But Syntax error occurs when I assemble the code

I'm using VS2017, and I wrote the code based on the instructions of the book.

```
add3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
mov eax, source1
add source2
mov destination, eax
ENDM

sub3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
mov eax, source1
sub source2
mov destination, eax
ENDM

mul3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
mov eax, source1
mul source2
mov destination, eax
ENDM

div3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
mov eax, source1
div source2
mov destination, source1
ENDM

.data
temp DWORD 0
x   DWORD ?
y   DWORD ?
z   DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

; Ex1. x = (w + y) * z
mov x, ?
mov y, 1
mov z, 2
mov w, 3
add3 temp, w, y     ; temp = w + y
mul3 x, temp, z     ; x = temp * z
mov eax, x
call    WriteInt
call    Crlf
```

Error Message I got is like below. A lot of syntax errors occurs when I debug my program.

```
13_4.asm(45): error A2008: syntax error : in instruction
1>13_4.asm(56): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(57): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(67): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(68): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(78): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(79): error A2008: syntax error : ,
1>13_4.asm(41): error A2009: syntax error in expression
1>13_4.asm(44): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
1>13_4.asm(45): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
1>13_4.asm(52): error A2009: syntax error in expression
1>13_4.asm(55): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
1>13_4.asm(58): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
1>13_4.asm(65): error A2009: syntax error in expression
1>13_4.asm(66): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
1>13_4.asm(75): error A2009: syntax error in expression
1>13_4.asm(77): error A2006: undefined symbol : w
```

Comment: "exec failed with error no such file or dir sourcery" What errors do you get?

Comment: Put those in the question, properly formatted.

Comment: I just edited my question! Thanks for editing my questions!

Comment: You're completely defeating the purpose of writing in assembly language.  You're basically creating a *very* inefficient compiler for a 3-operand language.  If you want a `temp` variable, use a register!  Also, x86 has a non-destructive `add` in the form of LEA, like `lea  edx, [ecx + edi]`  (It only works for register inputs and outputs).  Anyway, don't use these macros if you care *at all* about making efficient and compact code.  Just write in C and use an optimizing compiler if you want to write simpler-looking code.

Answer (score 1):

You are erroneously assuming that the `add`, `sub` instructions only take one parameter. This is only correct for `mul`, `imul`, `div` and `idiv`. So change your code to

```
add3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
  mov eax, source1
  add eax, source2
  mov destination, eax
ENDM

sub3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
  mov eax, source1
  sub eax, source2
  mov destination, eax
ENDM

mul3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
  mov eax, source1
  mul source2
  mov destination, eax  ; This is only the low 32-bit result of high(EDX):low(EAX)
ENDM

div3 MACRO destination, source1, source2
  xor edx, edx          ; Clear upper half of input EDX:EAX
  mov eax, source1
  div source2
  mov destination, eax
ENDM
```

These changes should fix some major errors of your code.
Now, regarding your `main` code:

```
; Ex1. x = (w + y) * z
mov x, ?            ; YOU CANNOT SET a register to an unknown value - it already is. Remove this line instead.
mov y, 1            ; OK
mov z, 2            ; OK
mov w, 3            ; OK
add3 temp, w, y     ; temp = w + y
mul3 x, temp, z     ; x = temp * z - Here 'x' is replaced with a value
mov eax, x          ; Set the parameter EAX to the value 'x'
call    WriteInt    ; Write the value in EAX and...
call    Crlf        ; ...proceed to the next line
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should result in the correct value `8`.

Also, add a

```
main ENDP
```

instruction at the end and, if necessary, a `main ENDS` as the last line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I modified my code based on your suggestions and I solved it :)